# Create a new database table every year

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I must create a new application based on an existing Excel application that uses a big database. For the new application I will use Microsoft Web Developer (VB.NET). The Excel application handles some orders and some data related to those orders.

Because it is a big database, I need to create programmatically a table for every year. For example: orders from 2013 will be in Orders_2013, orders from 2014 will be in Orders_2014 and so on ... But my new application should be able to search in all the tables; if I search for an order that from 2012 and now is 2013 the application should be able to search in the specific database table.

I must use the old database structure, and that is kind of a setback.
If I create a new database structure I must be able to import everything from the old database.

I need some guidance on how to build the application to create a new database, for every year.

I read something about SQL Management Studio, that I can use a task to create a script, for generating a new table every year, but I have not been able to create one so far. I will keep searching, but if someone knows what I'm looking for, please share that info.

Comment: SQL Server is perfectly able to handle big database. You will have far more difficulties to assemble to results from multiples DB than  correctly designing the DB. For example, what if tomorrow you will need queries like selecting the best customer of all times?

Comment: Why? Why not just create a single table and partition on year? (Not that I'm advocating partitioning at all).

Comment: One table is enough, improve your Database design!

Comment: What do you mean by BIG? Too big for Excel or for SQL server? Probably excel is your bottleneck with 1043k records. You could create tables already for 10 years in advance so you do not need to worry about that. You can search in SQL using unions over those 10 tables. It will work, but it is not pretty...

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: If you don't like the existing structure... change it now.  It would probably be easier to import data once then to live with a bad setup

Comment: Tasks can be scheduled as Jobs in SQL Server Agent.  To make an Annual Job, add a schedule to it that is "Monthly", and then set it to run every 12 months.

Answer (score 2):

Let me start by saying that I would advocate a single table design, while employing views to maintain backward compatibility. I am going to assume that you have your hands tied and cannot modify your table structure at all and hence unable to use a singe table.

In SQL Management Studio, you can create one of the yearly table in "Design View". Once done, you can right-click on the table and have it generate a CREATE TABLE script, which you can execute every year, with a different table name. I don't know if the SQL Management Studio can schedule it, but I would simple do it myself since its only once per year.

As for the unified search, you can create a view which is a union of all the year specific tables and search over that. This way you will only have to modify only the search component to work with the new view. However, you will also have to update this view every year as well, which should be pretty simple.

Comment: You can use the SQL Server Agent to schedule tasks as Jobs.