# Is it important to make divide database tables into time frames (such as years)?

Tags: php, database, database-design, normalization

I am just starting to make a mySQL database and one of the questions I am trying to figure out is, 'is it necessary to divide update my tables into time frames?'. Otherwise, if 5 years down the road I do a query, I am querying from a much larger table. I'm not sure about exactly how SQL performs queries and I don't know if there would be any significant downfall to just leaving the tables as they are...

As it is, my tables have a date column, part of the candidate key, and I have implemented date range queries, but is it a bad thing to leave everything in one table? (I do have multiple tables in at least 3NF-4NF form)

Also I took a look at answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14140899/create-a-new-database-table-every-year) question though I found the answers not to be very detailed and failed to give much explanation other than it's a relatively supported answer.

Comment: There is a thing called partitioning, but it's not possible to give you an advice without thorough explanation of what you're working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some key  points and proccess regarding this matter. i will try to go over some main architice patterns.

the problem with SQL start on a large row number roughly 5M and more. the problems are usually slowquery,if your database need to be updated constanly, lets say 2000-3000 hits per second, this can crash your servers.

To avoid heavy slow query you need to map the common table function and divide them in general to SELECT and INSERT/UPDATE.

For the SELECT i recomand use INNODB table to avoid Table locks, and think on Running a Chron Procedure (a script that will run automatclly on your server) that will create a smaller table that will hold a shorter time period than lifetime table. this will ensure a small size table that will work fast.

If you are planning on lots of hits. i recomand this idea keep the main table size under 15GB, decide on a time frame that from this point on there will be an Archive DB. Copy from the main table to the archive in small chunks every day. make sure that the archive is not limited in size (choose the right service to do so eg S3 at amazon can be great in storing SQL dump files. but this is not a SQL server you cant open this, you need to unzip it to SQL this can take long time. so the archive need to be a SQL server)
Archive pattern - Use SQL server with lots of RAM(128-256 GB) 4-8 CPU, break tables into tabels for time frames. try to keep it in 20M rows each.

. create a replication proccess to the main table -> a slave DB that will be only with read user permits.
now this set up will ensure that your table can take hits, its have a back up , and you keep all your data in an archive. another great feature is now you can send all you SELECT QUERIES to the slave DB . it will ensure that your SQL will not get stuck and you can use this to create YEAR,MONTH,DAY Aggreagate queries with no concern to the table size.

this plan will work on any free version of MYSQL and every servers that i know.

if you want more robost solution and time is not the main issue for your system i recomand GOOGLE app engine \ AMAZON cloud. for a unlimited STORAGE and Computing.

You can check your preformances by the slow query log and modify your DB to Hold more tabels in order to speed up your SQL. if you will use the same table for multiple users i think that you can look into Memcash Solutions that are great to display data over and over and saving time to connect and query your DB.

A few more points on the main slave relationship:

because you cant delete from your slave(read user), in order to delete data you must clean this from the main table. maybe it wasnt clear before, but when taking data to the archive you select data from the slave(again not to load heavy selects) and copy this, then you delete this data from the main table. the replication proccess will delete this from the slave as well. so the main and slave are the same almost all the time exept when this is archive proccess is happening. another point is traffic cost.. if the slave and the main are on the same server its will be cheaper but if the server goes down.. so you loose them together. hopefully you will place your archive on a diffrent server. if there is less traffic you can use the slave on a diffrent server and have a full back up all time for displaying data. when coding this make sure that if the data is not in the main table your code can accsess the archive and look there.

Hope this help.

Comment: +1 Well thought out answer. You mentioned to create a replication process from the main table to a slave db and use the slave db for all SELECT queries. Do you mean that all UPDATE/INSERT queries to be ran on the main table? If that is the case, would you suggest that the main table and slave table hold an equal amount of relevant rows (the rest being in the archive db)?

Comment: In general YES. because you cant delete from your slave(read user), in order to delete data you must clean this from the main table. maybe it wasnt clear before, but when taking data to the archive you select data from the slave(again not to load heavy selects) and copy this, then you delete this data from the main table. the replication proccess will delete this from the slave as well. so the main and slave are the same almost all the time exept when this is archive proccess is happening. another point is traffic cost.. if the slave and the main are on the same server its will be cheaper

Comment: but if the server goes down.. so you loose them together. hopefully you will place your archive on a diffrent server. if there is less traffic you can use the slave on a diffrent server and have a full back up all time for displaying data.  when coding this make sure that if the data is not in the main table your code can accsess the archive and look there.

Comment: thanks for the valuable answers. Very informative and a great help in giving me considerations for my database design. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are dealing with very large datasets or a system that won't be touched for 5 years... you will most likely have changed database engines by the time you run into problems and have to shard / partition your data further.

This is without knowing the context of your dataset however...

Comment: Why do you say that most likely I would have changed database engines in 5 years time? I would like to design the database well from start and try to account for future changes/needs rather than have to reformat (reorganize) my database later.